The number of ways of writing $k$ as a sum of the squares of "not so big" two elements
This question arises from the attempt to compute the Euler characteristic
of a space using a Morse function.
We fix a positive integer $n$. For each integer $k$ which satisfies the condition
$$1\leq k \leq (n-1)^2+n^2,$$
we define the set $S(n,k)$ by
$$S(n,k):=\begin{Bmatrix}(a,b) \in \mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z} \vert 0<a<b \leq n \quad  \text{and}\quad  a^2+b^2=k \end{Bmatrix}.$$
We set
$$P(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)^2+n^2} \vert S(n,k)\vert^2,$$
where $\vert \quad \vert$ denotes the cardinality.
Example:
(i) We have $S(8,65)=\begin{Bmatrix} (1,8),(4,7)\end{Bmatrix}$. On the other hand, we have $S(7,65)=\begin{Bmatrix}(4,7)\end{Bmatrix}$. In fact, the pair $(1,8)$ does not satisfy the condition "$b\leq n$".
(ii) The values of $P(n)$ for $1\leq n\leq 10$ are given as follows:
$$0,1,3,6,10,15,21,30,40,49.$$
Question: Can we get some information on $P(n)$? For example, what is the first-order asymptotic growth of $P(n)$ as $n \to \infty$?
Comment:
Theta series of square lattice, which I denote by $r(k)$, is defined as
$$r(k):=\vert \begin{Bmatrix}(a,b) \in \mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z} \vert a^2+b^2=k\end{Bmatrix}\vert.$$
We can find its property in https://oeis.org/A004018. In fact, when $k$ is small, it is also possible to enumerate the elements of the set
$$T(k):=\begin{Bmatrix}(a,b) \in \mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z} \vert 0<a<b \quad \text{and} \quad a^2+b^2=k\end{Bmatrix}.$$
But I don't know how to manage the condition "$b \leq n$".

The numbers you listed are "triangular number + some extras" where the "extras" are due to some $k$ values having multiple "sum of squares" ways. When you know those $k$ values , then you can easily get the "extras" & then try to get the numbers you want.
